# Call API using axios and Redux Saga always return undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm using axios and redux saga to call api and check with local input, but redux saga always return undefined

**Function to get data using axios**

```
export function requestGetUser() {
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/khanh21011999/demo/user',
  });
}
```

**Action file**

```
export const getUser = () => ({
    type: actionList.GET_USER,
});
export const setUser = (user) => ({
    type: actionList.SET_USER,
    user,
});
export const GetUserInfo = (user, password) => {
    return{
        type: actionList.GET_USER_INFO,
        data: {user, password},
    }
};
export const LoginSuccess = (data) => {
    return {
        type: actionList.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        data,
    };
};

export const LoginFailed = (data) => {
    return {
        type: actionList.LOGIN_FAIL,
        data,
    };
};

export const Logout = (data) => {
    return {
        type: actionList.LOG_OUT,
        data
    };
};
```

**Redux-saga part**

I log everything but it return `undefined`

```
export function* LoginsSagaFunc() {
    yield takeLatest('GET_USER_INFO', loginSaga)

}
function* SaveToAsyncStorage(data) {
    try {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(
            'data',
            JSON.stringify({
                username: data.username,
                password: data.password
            }))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error save to Storage');
    }
}

function* loginSaga(action) {

    console.log('Saga is working')
    const getJson = yield call(requestGetUser)
    const getJsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getJson))

    const getJsonUsername = String(getJsonData.username)
    console.log('JsonUsername '+getJsonUsername)
    console.log("local data " + action.data.username)
    console.log('getJsonData '+getJsonData)
    console.log('GetJson '+getJson)
    

    const getJsonPassword = String(getJsonData.password)

    if (String(action.data.username) === getJsonUsername) {
        if (String(action.data.password) === getJsonPassword) {
            console.log('saga login success')
            yield put({type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'})
            SaveToAsyncStorage(action.data)
        }
        else {
            console.log('saga password fail')
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("saga user fail")
    }
}
```

**The reducer**

```
const initStateAuth={
        isAuth:false,
        isLogIn:false
    }
    const AuthReducer =(state=initStateAuth,action)=>{
        switch (action.type) {
        case actionList.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
          {
            console.log('action : LOG IN SUCCESS');
            return {
                    
              isAuth: true,
                        isLogIn: true,
            };
          }
            case actionList.GET_USER_INFO:
                {
                    return initStateAuth
                }
        case actionList.LOGIN_FAIL:
          {
           
            return initStateAuth
          }
        case actionList.LOG_OUT:
          {
            return initStateAuth
          }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    
    
    }
    export default AuthReducer
```

**How i dispatch on the main file**

```
 function LoginScreen({navigation}) {
    // set timeout ID for setTimeOut()
    const timeIdRef = React.useRef(null);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [username, getUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, getPassword] = useState('')

    // handleInput = (e) => {
    //  getUserInfo(e.target.value);
    // };

    // mock user from fake api
    useEffect(() => {
        // dispatch(getUser());
        
    }, [dispatch]);
    dispatch(GetUserInfo(username, password));
    //  const handlegetdata= ({user,password})=>{
    // dispatch(GetUserInfo(user,password))
    // // }

    // console.log(handleGetdata.user)


    const user = useSelector((state) => {
        return state.User.user;
    });
    // console.log('user' + username)
    //  console.log('userJSon'+user.username)
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            if (timeIdRef.current) {
                // make sure this is always cleared in case clearTo is never called
                clearTimeout(timeIdRef.current);
            }
        };
    }, [timeIdRef]);
    // console.log();

    const Login = useSelector((state) => {
        return state.LoginAction.loginStatus;
    });
    // console.log(Login)
    //   const initModal = false;
    // eslint-disable-next-line require-jsdoc
    function handleLogin() {
        dispatch({type: 'changeLogin'});
    }
    function handlDefault() {
        dispatch({type: 'getDefault'});
    }

    // not show??
    // console.log(username);
    // console.log('Login ' + Login)
    //   const [show, doShow] = useState(initModal);

    // const [visible, UpdateView] = useState(false)

    // Show modal dialog
    //   function ChangeModalValue() {
    //     console.log(show);
    //     doShow(!show);
    //   }
    // setTimer after Model Appear

    function SetTimer() {
        handleLogin();
        if (timeIdRef.current) {
            // clear any previous timeIdRef to avoid multiple button click activate multiple setTimeout
            clearTimeout(timeIdRef.current);
        }
        const timeID = setTimeout(() => {
            navigation.navigate('Home');
        }, 3000);
        timeIdRef.current = timeID;
    }

    function clearTO() {
        clearTimeout(timeIdRef.current);
        timeIdRef.current = null;
        handlDefault();
    }

    // make text black when check complete
    function getTextStyle(isValid) {
        if (isValid) {
            return {
                color: 'black',
            };
        }

        return {
            color: 'grey',
        };
    }
    //   function getLoginText() {
    //     return <CirclesLoader />;
    //   }
    // function hideText(visible){
    //     if(isDisabler)

    // }
    const loginValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string().email('Please enter valid email').required('Email Address is Required'),
        password: Yup.string()
            .min(8, ({min}) => `Password must be at least ${min} characters`)
            .required('Password is required'),
    });
    return (
        <View style={styles.ViewStyle}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>Login To System</Text>

            <Formik
                validateOnMount
                validationSchema={loginValidationSchema}
                initialValues={{email: '', password: ''}}
                onSubmit={value => {
                    getUsername(value.email)
                    getPassword(value.password)
                    SetTimer()
                }}
            // () => navigation.navigate('Login')
            >
                {({handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors, touched, isValid}) => (
                    <View>
                        <TextInput
                            name="email"
                            placeholder="Email Address"
                            style={styles.TextInputForm}
                            onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                            onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                            value={values.email}
                            keyboardType="email-address"
                        />
                        {errors.email && touched.email && <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errors.email}</Text>}
                        <TextInput
                            name="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                            onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
                            value={values.password}
                            secureTextEntry
                            style={styles.TextInputForm}
                        />
                        {errors.password && touched.password && (
                            <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errors.password}</Text>
                        )}

                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={handleSubmit}
                            style={styles.ButtonLogin}
                            disabled={!isValid || values.email === ''}>
                            {/* <CirclesLoader size={20} dotRadius={7} /> */}
                            <Text style={getTextStyle(isValid)}>Login</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <View>
                            <Modal transparent visible={Login}>
                                <View
                                    style={{
                                        backgroundColor: '#000000',
                                        flex: 1,
                                        justifyContent: 'center',
                                        alignContent: 'center',
                                    }}>
                                    <View style={styles.ModalStyle}>
                                        <CirclesLoader />
                                        <TextLoader
                                            textStyle={{
                                                fontSize: 25,
                                                marginTop: 20,
                                            }}
                                            text="Logging you in"
                                        />
                                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={clearTO} style={styles.ButtonBack}>
                                            <Text>Go back</Text>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </Modal>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Also, the action get the data when i press, BUT it return undefined in redux-saga part, so username always so equal, what happened??

**Why data show in redux debugger but i can't see it on saga, and why data i fetch from axios return undefinded?**

a short gif to show what happened
[image]

[image]
Please help, thank you a lot

FULL CODE : https://codesandbox.io/s/github/khanh21011999/Trainning-react-native

Answer (score 1):

In the axios API call, you need to code for a successful or a failed response as follows:

```
export function requestGetUser() {
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/khanh21011999/demo/user',
  })
.done (function(data) {
    //Get your data here upon successful fetch
  })
.fail (function() {
    console.log("Failed to fetch data");
  })
.always (function() {
    console.log("This function always executes whether success or fail");
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how to i get data in the `function(data)`, i mean, how to access these data in redux-saga file, im very new, please give me an example

Comment: How to get these data? is `return data` legit?

Comment: But it show successful when i use console.log https://ibb.co/r5xFjF3

Comment: Please help, i'm stuck with this for days :((

Comment: Hi Khanh. You should get the data from within the .done function itself by coding inside the function. You can do a console.log(data) there to see the data (data[0].fieldname, data[1].fieldname...etc). There are also other methods like putting the data in global variables which is not a good way.

Comment: it show successful but data return undefied https://ibb.co/84rvM2V , is my json format correct??

Comment: Link to json https://my-json-server.typicode.com/khanh21011999/demo/user

Comment: Hi Khanh. Can you try data[0].username instead of data.username and data[0].password instead of data.password?

Comment: It said TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined https://ibb.co/yhdNxF2, i really don't understand why it always return `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

First of all your sandbox is not working so make sure it works for all.
Second try using async/await like this in your code, I'm not able to test it because your sandbox is crashing.
`export async function requestGetUser() { return await axios.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/khanh21011999/demo/user'); }`

Comment: Sorry, i'm using react-native, so just show the code but i'm not know how to mạke them run on web :((

Comment: i tried your method but it show like this https://ibb.co/d2BtSQg

Comment: When you are explicitly calling `get` then why are you passing object with method and url prop, just try axios the same way I had written in my answer.

Comment: Or you could simply ignore async/await and return with then and catch block.

Comment: I think i will go for easier way, i'm just started learn react and react native for 3 weeks with NO web background, this is so much to me, but thank for your answer, i appreciate that

Comment: Khanh, can I ask you to just backtrack a little bit ... inside the .done() function(data) {}) of the axios call, if you just insert the code, console.log('data: ' + data); is it returning a data object?